# preg_match_all Pattern Search

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

My subject is

```
some html codes<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.somedomain.com/args/">Some Title</a></h3>some html codes
```

My current pattern is:

```
"/<h3 class="r"><a href="\/url?\?q\=http(...)/"
```

The result is:

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://
```

I wanted to get the exact url, http://www.somedomain.com/args/
or just `<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.somedomain.com/args/">Some Title</a></h3>` so i can parse it to return the url.

but i could not make it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Try this regex with `preg_match_all()`: `\b(https?://[^\s()<>]+\.[^\s()<>]+)\b`. [See **demo**](https://eval.in/136152)

Answer (score 0):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/mB5bQ0)

Try this:

```
'/<h3 class="r"><a href="\/url?\?q\=(http.*)\/"/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'some html codes<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.somedomain.com/args/">Some Title</a></h3>some html codes'
preg_match_all('!http://(.*)"!', $string, $result_array);
print_r($result_array);
```

Try it.